# color marker change periodically

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

we want to set a timer each monday to change the color of an already existing marker

```
class CustomTask extends TimerTask {

    public CustomTask() {

        Marker mf4 = MapsActivity.this.mf4;

    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            mf4 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f4).title("Γ.ΔΡΟΣΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error running thread " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
public void runTask () {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(
            Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
            Calendar.TUESDAY
    );
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


    Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object

    // Start running the task on Monday at 15:40:00, period is set to 8 hours
    // if you want to run the task immediately, set the 2nd parameter to 0
    time.schedule(new CustomTask(), calendar.getTime(), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24));
}
```

Thats how we add the markers in our code on class onMapReady.
We want to change mf4(marker 4) to change its color every monday and keep its changed color for 24 hours since it began and when the time ends return to its original color.

```
    mf1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f1).title("Κοινωνικό Ιατρείο- Φαρμακείο Ναυπακτίας").snippet("Τηλέφωνο: 2634 400064 Ώρες: 9:30π.μ.–1:30μ.μ."));
    mf2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f2).title("Φαρμακείο Ντουραμπά Αικατερίνη και Σια Ε.Ε."));
    mf3 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f3).title("Φαρμακείο Ιωάννη Ράπτη Ναύπακτος"));
    mf4 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f4).title("Γ.ΔΡΟΣΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ"));
    mf5 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f5).title("Φαρμακειο Π Θεοφανης κ ΣΙΑ"));
    mf6 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f6).title("Pharmacy Dionisious"));
    mf7 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f7).title("Φαρμακείο ΠΑΠΑΘΑΝΑΣΗΣ ΑΘΑΝΑΣΙΟΣ"));
    mf8 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f8).title("ΠΑΝΑΓΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ ΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΗ & ΣΙΑ Ε.Ε."));
    mf9 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f9).title("Φαρμακείο ΑΝΤΩΝΑΚΟΥ ΕΥΑΓΓΕΛΙΑ Β."));
    mf10 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f10).title("Φαρμακείο ΒΑΣΙΛΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ ΧΡΙΣΤΙΝΑ"));
    mf11 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f11).title("Φαρμακείο ΑΝΔΡΕΟΠΟΥΛΟΣ ΑΘΑΝΑΣΙΟΣ ΟΕ"));
    mf12 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(f12).title("Φαρμακείο Κούμπιος Μ. Νικόλαος Ναύπακτος"));
```

Comment: Can i share you all the code or something so you can see  it all?

Comment: The best bet is to share the minimal amount of code that shows a complete picture of what you've got and what you've tried so far. Take out things that aren't relevant, leave in anything related to what you're trying to achieve and what options you've tried so far. Check [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Comment: First of all, what i want to do is make an app that shows the pharmacies on my local area and change its marker color whenever its on duty.I have the static markers on my map but i cant seem to find how to change the markers,i tried the calendar and timer task above and it doesnt seem to work at all.

Comment: Hello Johnny, In case that you need to make some action with data every fixed period, I suggest to you use workmanager (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)